# AngularJS UI-Router prevent double fetching on initial page loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**SCENARIO**: 1) We’d a full blown AngularJS SPA, and we’re using AngularJS UI-Router in state management; 2) Lately we were exploring “Graceful Degradation” so our project could be more accessible for users, machines, and SE; 3) We’d reached a technical implementation were we’re delivering the fully rendered HTML markup to the user on first page load, and any subsequent requests are delegated to AngularJS to handle with no more page refreshes at all within user’s browsing journey

**EXTENSION**: In our implementation, on the first page load we’ve the fully rendered HTML markup already delivered with all required data -yes, complete page content-; This implementation works perfectly with Javascript DISABLED and for search engines as well, but on the other hand for users with Javascript ENABLED since that delivered HTML markup contains AngularJS placeholders & directives it begins reprocessing the page once the DOM is ready, and of course refetch data from server, and re-update view containers. So we’re processing the page twice, hitting the server twice, and adding wasted headache to both the client & server (ONLY ON THE FIRST PAGE LOAD).

**QUESTION**: How could we prevent AngularJS  from processing the initial page loaded?